# rotary encoder, got a 20ppr but need more like 200 ppr

Tags: encoder, guitar-pedal

I'm a tinkerer who is attempting to turn a guitar pedal into a remote tempo control for a drum machine, which uses a rotary encoder. In place of the potentiometer in the guitar pedal, I have put in a rotary encoder 858-EN11-HSM1BF20. This works, but the guitar pedal's range of travel only gives the encoder about a quarter of a full turn, just a few clicks. I have tried searching on octopart of "200PPR enocder", or other similar values. I'm in need of at least a hundred PPR for the pedal to be useful.

I'm in need of either an encoder that is around 200 PPR and has a standard 6mm diameter shaft, or a guitar pedal that has gearing in it to turn the encoder many times. Or, maybe somebody has an idea I haven't considered?

I have been unable to locate any encoders beyond 30 PPR on Octopart, Digi-Key or Mouser. But then, I'm just a tinkerer and really don't know what's out there. Any suggestions for a high-PPR encoder, or maybe a guitar pedal that uses gearing that will allow me to get many turns on that 20PPR encoder?

Comment: Try usdigital, they have what you are looking for

Comment: Don't you mean PPR (pulses per revolution) instead of PPM?  (PPM usually means for parts per million.)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a better idea to emulate the rotary encoder with a microcontroller, a potentiometer, and a couple of small solid state relays or optoisolators.  Generally a rotary encoder presents two SPST switch closure contacts that will output a quadrature waveform.  It would be relatively simple to map ADC readings of the voltage off of the center tap of a pot into a quadrature encoder signal with an arbitrary number of pulses per rotation so you can better match the range of the pedal to the range required by the drum machine.

Comment: Potentiometers stink. They make noise, are never linear and will die soon if actuated the way this project insinuates. Furthermore the asker will likel already have a microcontroller at work. What else will take the Q coded signals?

Comment: Sounds like he is trying to hack an existing device - relocating the built-in encoder of a commercial drum machine into a pedal for foot control. My suggestion is that simply using a higher resolution encoder may not be the best solution. By adding a microcontroller in between, you can adjust the full pedal range to any arbitrary number of encoder ticks. It would even be possible to implement a nonlinear mapping of some sort if desired.

Comment: I am indeed hacking existing devices. The volume pedal is a cheap $25 volume pedal from Amazon, and the single electronic component in there is a basic potentiometer. The actuation mechanism is little more than a door handle that gives about 60 degrees of twist on that 6mm shaft.

Answer (score 0):

Sparkfun has a [200 PPR encoder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10932), but the shaft is only 4mm.  However they have a [1024 PPR encoder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11102) at the same price, with a 6 mm shaft.

Comment: That 1024 PPR encoder certainly would work as far as the physical dimensions go, and even the PPR might work, but the challenge for me is: How to get the grey code from that device, and turn it into what the effects box thinks is the output from the mechanical rotary encoder.